# Connect Mongodb to Sails JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo, nosql

ive read various tutorials and instructions how to connect sails to js. Every tutorial is telling me to do this. I am new to mongodb btw.

I followed the instructions

1. install sails-mongo (npm install)
2. Edit the config/connection

   ```
   mongo: {
     adapter: 'sails-mongo',
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 54321,
     database:'dbname'
    }
   ```
3. Edit the config/models.js

   ```
   connection:'mongo'
   ```
4. Edit the local.js

   ```
   connections: {
     mongodb: {
     host      : 'localhost',
     port      : 54321,
     database  : 'dbname'
     }
   }
   ```

so in my api/model/User.js

```
 module.exports = {
   attributes:{
      name: {  
        type: 'string'
      },
      employedIn:{ 
       collection:'company'
      }
    },
    findUsers :function(opts,cb){

      Users.findOne(opts).exec(function (err, theUser) {
         // to do
         // i wanna show the data of the user
      });
    }

 }
```

I run console.log(Users) but I didnt find column/documents there.

Now, how am i going to get the collection named users from mongodb? 
(Just like 'SELECT * FROM users' in SQL or db.users.find().pretty() )

Comment: have you tried `console.log(theUser)` instead of `console.log(Users)` ?

Comment: I did. Underfined.

Comment: @dvxam if there is no error, it will show null.

Comment: Your model is caller User, not Users. Inside Model you can use 'this' (not in callbacks). If collection in database is called 'users' add tableName: 'users'

Comment: If helped add to you question a solution that next person would know how to fix similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You query a waterline model by models `find` or `findOne` method. You create a new record by `create`, update by `update` and delete by `destroy` methods. There are some more methods exposed by query interface. You have to call `exec` and pass a callback to it, to get it run. Documentation is here: [Waterline Query Interface](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query.md)

So basically it's just:

```
User.create({
  name: 'Max Mustermann'
}).exec(function(console.log));

User.find().exec(function(console.log));

User.create({
  name: 'Peter Pan'
}).exec(function(console.log));

User.find().exec(console.log);

User.findOne({
  where: { name: 'Max Mustermann' }
}).exec(function(err, user) {
  user.destroy().exec(console.log);
});
```

You do not need a custom `findUsers` method on your model. This is just find:

```
// /api/model/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes:{
    name: {  
      type: 'string'
    },
    employedIn:{ 
      collection:'company'
    }
  }
}
```

You should use `sails console` to test.

Comment: @Lemon: Why did you unaccept the answer? Is there still an issue left?